# SQL copy from one table insert into another - using a where clause

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a table called Details, this table has _id field as the primary key. For each record in Details I have seven more records in another table called as Notifications. The _id field of Details is mapped with PrimaryId field of Notifications table.

Now I want to copy two columns namely imageUri and BirthDate from Details into Notifications where _id of Details is equal to PrimaryId field of Notifications.

So far I have tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO Notifications (imageUri, DOB) SELECT (imageUri, birthDate) FROM Details
```

But I dont have any clue how to add the Where clause. Please give me a heading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `WHERE` condition in your `SELECT` part like

```
INSERT INTO Notifications (imageUri, DOB) 
SELECT d.imageUri, d.birthDate 
FROM Details d
JOIN Notifications n
ON d._id = n.PrimaryId
```

Moreover, I think you are actually looking for doing an `UPDATE` and not `INSERT` since you said in your post

> For each record in Details I have seven more records in another table
>   called as Notifications

In that case, if you `INSERT` then you will add new records with `null` in rest of the field but not `update` old records. Moreover, for your case you don't need a `WHERE` clause rather a `JOIN clause` and specify the condition.

```
update Notifications
set imageUri = (select imageUri
                     from Details WHERE _id = Notifications.PrimaryId), 
DOB = (select DOB
            from Details WHERE _id = Notifications.PrimaryId)
```

Comment: Where? That is a bit confusing!

Comment: Yes I am confused about the same very thing - What should the condition be like - syntax?

Comment: I don't think you should be doing an `INSERT` .. rather you want to perform a `UPDATE` here. Check edited answer.

Comment: No I have upgraded my DB version and altered the tables to include these fresh columns.

Comment: If you `INSERT` then you will add new records but not update old records. Moreover, for your case you don't need a `WHERE` clause rather a `JOIN` clause and specify the condition.

Comment: Let me check on that!

Comment: I am sorry, but its giving me a syntax error. At inner.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
insert into Notifications (imageUri, DOB)
AS select d.imageUri, d.birthDate
from Details d, Notifications n
where d._id = n.PrimaryId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO Notifications (imageUri, DOB)
SELECT D.imageUri, D.birthDate FROM Details D
INNER JOIN Notifications N on d._id_FieldName=N._id_FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add your where clause at the end of your query:

```
INSERT INTO Notifications (imageUri, DOB) SELECT (imageUri, birthDate) FROM Details WHERE ...
```

You can see details here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm